# Manually create framework from static library

Tags: objective-c, ios, frameworks, static-libraries

I have question about creating framework manually from static library (for example `LibraryName`). I tested this solution:

- created folder `LibraryName.framework`
- created subfolder `LibraryName.framework/Headers` and copied headers from source library
- renamed `LibraryName.a` to file `LibraryName.framework/LibraryName`

and it is working under Xcode. But I have question: is it good way to do it like this ?

-- 
Regards 
Adam

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is fine. You can even link the static library against its dependencies and create a dynamic library. Both solutions will work.