# How can I convert my custom classes into a custom framework in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios4, ios6, ios-frameworks

Is it possible to create an own obj-C Cocoa Touch framework by using classes created already.How can I make it useful for others by converting into a custom framework using Xcode?

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you should creare static library. @Antonio MG gave a great suggestion about [Creating a Static Library in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-status-library-in-ios-tutorial).

After that you can create framework from static lib and headers. How to do this you can see in this [SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476750/manually-create-framework-from-static-library)

Comment: Thanks , I Already tried them but unfortunately not reached to success.If you know, kindly share some simple methods.Because I am new to iOS.